# having an issue parsing json in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am very new to coding. I have looked at many examples on the web but just can't seem to find what I am looking for.

https://data.calgary.ca/resource/k7p9-kppz.json

**RETURNED JSON:**

```
[
    {
        ":@computed_region_4a3i_ccfj": "1",
        ":@computed_region_4b54_tmc4": "8",
        ":@computed_region_kxmf_bzkv": "29",
        ":@computed_region_p8tp_5dkv": "5",
        "description": "Glenmore Trail / 14 Street SW (West)",
        "latitude": "50.9938095441965",
        "location": {
            "latitude": "50.9938095441965",
            "longitude": "-114.094978074903",
            "human_address": "{\"address\": \"\", \"city\": \"\", \"state\": \"\", \"zip\": \"\"}"
        },
        "longitude": "-114.094978074903",
        "quadrant": "SW",
        "url": {
            "url": "http://trafficcam.calgary.ca/loc111.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        ":@computed_region_4a3i_ccfj": "2",
        ":@computed_region_4b54_tmc4": "7",
        ":@computed_region_kxmf_bzkv": "62",
        ":@computed_region_p8tp_5dkv": "7",
        "description": "Memorial Drive / 9 Street NW",
        "latitude": "51.0536259017801",
        "location": {
            "latitude": "51.0536259017801",
            "longitude": "-114.081180764729",
            "human_address": "{\"address\": \"\", \"city\": \"\", \"state\": \"\", \"zip\": \"\"}"
        },
        "longitude": "-114.081180764729",
        "quadrant": "NW",
        "url": {
            "url": "http://trafficcam.calgary.ca/loc59.jpg"
        }
    },
```

I am trying to get `description` and `url`. 
I don't have a problem getting `description`, but when I try to get `url`, it throws an error.

Comment: Hi, Can you show us the error?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: You'll need to add some code and the error in question. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @blainec: You can see difference in json itself.. description is direct element but if you see URL is nested.. so finally if you are trying to access description like $json['description'] then url should be $json['url']['url']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `json_decode();` with `true` as `second` param, if you add `true` as second param then you can get assosiative array [array of array] else array of object

```
$jsonToarray = json_decode($jsonData,true);// it will return array of array with assosiative format
```

And to Get `url`

```
echo $jsonToarray['url']['url'];die;
```

> You can use `description` directly because it is not nested but `url` is nested array so there is a difference between them